# C# casing convention for hexadecimal literals?

Tags: c#, hex, literals, naming-conventions

I like unity and I want to keep my code style guidelines strictly consistent.

So consider this `ulong` literal:

```
var x = 0xFFUL;
```

vs.

```
var x = 0xffUL;
```

It might be a stupid question but I hate when my code is not consistent even in these negligible things, so I'd like to know what's hex numbers like for the C# project team...

Comment: I recommend not to use hexa numbers at all. When a developer see that he has to do math in his mind to convert it to decimal, If the number is enough large then brain won't help, you need some converter. So please avoid it and simply use decimal number system.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it's a project that massively deals with binary data. Translating all the literals to decimal would be silly, and since I have a BUNCH of those constant literals hence my question.

Comment: Well, what about `(1 << 8) - 1`? It depends on the location, of course. Oh, and don't forget that you could also write `0xfful` or `0xFFul` :D There's quite a few options. All in all, though, this is quite an opinion-based question, so it might be closed down.

Comment: @Luaan The common convention for the literal suffix is uppercase. So the that the `l` is not confused with `1`. If I'm not wrong VS even issues a warning for using a lowercase literal suffix. [Here](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap08/ch08_7.html)'s another source that talks about avoiding lowercase in literal suffixes, it's in Java tho, but should be valid in C# too, it does refer only to `long` however.

Comment: And regarding @SriramSakthivel's comment, I'm just used to read the hexadecimal. Hex is a numeric system introduced in order to simplify binary. For my project, hex is gorgeous, and I'm not willing to replace it with shifting operators or any hacks to be able to use decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To date, the most popular format for representing hexadecimal literals is 0 to 9 and A to F.

You can confirm that the use of uppercase characters is most popular by referring to the hexadecimal Wikipedia entry [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Using_0.E2.80.939_and_A.E2.80.93F).

Hence follow the ["wisdom of the crowd"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom_of_the_crowd) and use 0-9, A-F.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually looking at Microsoft's code base and find inconsistencies there too.
[Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs) it's lowercase while [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binaryreader.cs) it's uppercase.

So I believe the true answer is there is no convention about that, and one should pick his favorite naming.

Also searching [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) I'm not finding anything about hex casing.